# Latest version of Material UI Calendar styling is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, calendar, mui-x-date-picker

I am working on Material UI with React (refer Package json for versions). Trying to implement the calendar functionality. But the CSS for the same is not working. ***Wanted to try adding CDN trick on `index.html`, but in the MUI documentation it is saying strictly not recommended*** for production environment.

**Here is my package.json details for version of MUI & React:**

```
{
  "name": "date_picker_react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.17",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers-pro": "^6.18.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

**My App.jsx code:**

```
import{Chip, Divider} from '@mui/material';
import CalenderComp from './components/CalenderComp.jsx';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Divider><Chip label="Calender"/></Divider>
      <CalenderComp />
      
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**My Calendar Component Code:**

```
import { useState} from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react'
import { Calendar } from 'react-date-range';

function CalenderComp() {

  const [calendar, setCalender] = useState('');
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  function handleSelect(date){
    console.log(date);
  }
  return (
    <div style={{'textAlign': 'center'}}>
      <TextField 
      label="Select Date"
      name="date"
      variant='outlined'
      value={calendar}
      onClick={()=> setOpen(open => !open)}
      />
      <br />

      {open &&
      <Calendar 
      date = {new Date()}
      onChange={handleSelect}
      />}
    </div>
  )
}

export default CalenderComp
```

The Final output when I click on the text field to view the calendar:

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18f73.png)

Why the CSS is soo absurd? I did install MUI as it is described in MUI website. Please Help.

I tried reinstalling MUI on npm, but still not working

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range#usage, Don't see you importing the relevant styles